# Convergence of a sequence of a continuously differentiable function

Tags: convergence-divergence

Let $f(x): \mathbb{C}^M \rightarrow R$ be a continuously differentiable function of complex vector $x$. Besides, let us assume that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of $x$. If we know that sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to a value (less than $\infty$), can we claim that $\{x_n\}$ also converges?

**Note:** we also know that $\{f(x_n)\}$ is increasing and bounded from the top.

Comment: $f$ could be a constant function...

Comment: We know that it is not a constant function

Comment: $x_n= (1-1/n, n)$, $f(a,b)=a$